Is there a way to change the location of a dataset on Bigquery
Sometimes after writing a SQL query. it turns up that the required table does not exist in the region of choice where the dataset has been saved in
I don know what to do. I have checked youtube but the results are inconclusive. I cannot understand what I am supposed to do

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If the table you are querying does not exist in the specified database or schema, you should consider replicating the table's data to your used Schema or dataBase, otherwise your filters will be inaccurate.
